# Name server setup in XAMPP based server?

Tags: apache, xampp

I want to setup the apache virtual host in my server

My registered Domain name is       www.abcd.com

Name server1: NS1.ABCD.COM

Name server2: NS2.ABCD.COM

My static ip: 112.123.124.195

I can access my website from the static ip address shown above, but now want to setup the vhost file to access this server from the www.abcd.com

My current virtual host file is as following. Please help me to set up this file for accessing from the registered domain.

```
enter code here
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "G:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "G:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>

enter code here
```

Comment: http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/  how to setup virtualhost on xampp. In this case should be used the ServerAlias

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am not able to setup via that method,, there is not explaiation about the server alias in that tutorial,  i am using windows 7, and want some detailed or step by step  detal to setu pi t...please help me solve this

Answer (score 2):

> 

you could put something like this in your httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost 210.212.143.195>
    ServerName www.abcd.com
    ServerAlias abcd.com   
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot the/root/to your/webfolder
    ServerName example.com

    <Directory "the/root/to your/webfolder">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

than you should include in your windows host file (windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts)
If you want under localhost

```
 210.212.143.195 www.abcd.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply <br>    it is not working for me....my static ip address for the website in the 210.212.143.195  please give me some idea to bind this ip address to the domain.  <br>

Comment: so i have been refactoring a bit the http-vhost.conf. You should give a try. Remember, after editing those files you have to restart your apache web server and do not forget to define your document root in the httpd-vhosts.conf. Is your domains real name www.abcd.com or just was an example. Your ip can not be pinged

Comment: Thank you for your reply,   my live ip address is 210.212.143.195 but the www.abcd.com is the exapmple domain proivided to you.   i know to restart the apache serv er after changing the httpd-vhosts.cong file. thanks for that....but still not working

Comment: to bind the IP address to the Domain name you need to do it at the DNS (Domain Name Server) Usually where you purchased the Domain from

Comment: short and working. On local instead of ip write localhost, and on windows 127.0.0.1