# Access wordpress website from phone hosted locally through Xammp

Tags: iphone, wordpress, apache, xampp, local

I have a test WordPress website hosted locally by my PC. This is fine but i am now wanting to test the website on a phone and tablet (iPhone and iPad).

I have looked online for all the options and i can't get any to work (changing the httpd files and i have tried everything else) I can type my IP address of my PC with the port number added at the end and this takes me to the Xampp control panel page but i cant access my website by typing 'IPaddress/websitename'.

Can someone please give me a full step by step of what i need to do to be able to see my locally xampp WordPress website from my iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is probably not on the same network as your PC, and you might not be sharing your XAMPP website over the network. It would be possible to make your website available to your phone, but it is likely to be quite a lot of work, and might be insecure.

A better idea would be to shrink your desktop browser down to phone / tablet size, and check the layout that way. You can even throttle the internet speed, to simulate slower connections, and choose specific device models. On Chrome, this is called [device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/). You will need to turn on Chrome developer tools first, which is done by clicking View -> Developer -> Developer Tools, in the Chrome toolbar. You will see a little icon there (see the link for a screenshot).

If you are going to make the site live, you should still probably check it with a real phone / tablet, but for the first steps, using 'device mode' is a good place to start.

Comment: My phone is on the same network as my PC hence why i can type my PC IP with the port number and i get to the XAMPP PHP admin page. I know i can change the browser setting but that inst the point as i want to check the usability form a phone and tablet not just how it looks.

Comment: If anyone else has any suggestions they will be much appreciated

Comment: I don't mind if it is insecure as its my home network and it will be for 30 minutes to try and test the site.

Comment: What port is the PHP admin page being served over? If you are typing the port manually, I am assuming it isn't port 80. Could your PC firewall be blocking incoming traffic on port 80, but allowing other ports? Maybe try turning off the firewall momentarily, to see if it is firewall-related.

Comment: Hi, i type 192.168.0.20:80. Firewall rules setup to allow port 80 and 443.

Comment: I have read online and tried all options but i just don't know what i am doing wrong hence why i need someone to give me all the steps

Comment: Sounds like you have port clash then - i.e. your PHPmyadmin page is being served instead of your Wordpress website, because they are both using port 80. You need to set up name based serving, so the XAMPP server knows which website you are requesting when you connect to port 80. Have you added the `ServerName` section in your vhost config? Check this link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844624/name-server-setup-in-xampp-based-server

Comment: You will also need to setup your PC's hosts file, so your PC knows that your URL is being served locally, not on the public internet. That link shows how to do that as well. The other option is to move PHPmyadmin to another port - eg port 8080, so only 1 site is available on port 80 - which will be your Wordpress site.

Comment: Thanks for the info... Do you know how i can set what port my WordPress site is hosted on though?

Comment: You set that in the vhosts file where is says `*:80`. 8080 is a common alternative port.

Comment: I have already looked at that linked post when doing my own research but again i just got the PHPadmin page. The link doesn't really tell me where to put what code etc. What will i need to put in my host file as a don't have a web url as such to place in there. If i but 'localhost:80/mywebsite' i will just get bottlenecks?

Comment: okay i will give this a try when i get home. So in the Vhosts file just change anywhere it says 80 to 8080